How to properly declare and use variables in Borneo SQL queries?
I'm currently working with the Borneo SDK in Python to execute SQL queries against an Oracle NoSQL database. I'm running into issues when trying to declare and use variables within my SQL statements. Specifically, I'm getting syntax errors related to variable declarations.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import logging
from borneo import PrepareRequest, QueryRequest

# Set up logging
logging.getLogger().info("Starting the query execution")

# SQL statement with variable declarations
statement = '''
DECLARE $mailaddress STRING;
DECLARE $nickname STRING;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mailaddress = $mailaddress AND nickname = $nickname
'''

logging.getLogger().info("Preparing the statement")
prequest = PrepareRequest().set_statement(statement)
logging.getLogger().info("Prepared the statement request")

try:
    # Prepare the statement
    presult = handle.prepare(prequest)
    logging.getLogger().info("Statement prepared")

    # Get the prepared statement
    pstatement = presult.get_prepared_statement()
    logging.getLogger().info("Got the prepared statement")

    # Set variables
    pstatement.set_variable('$mailaddress', mailaddress)
    pstatement.set_variable('$nickname', nickname)
    logging.getLogger().info("Set variables for the prepared statement")

    # Execute the query
    qrequest = QueryRequest().set_prepared_statement(pstatement)
    qiresult = handle.query_iterable(qrequest)

    # Process the results
    userId = ""
    for row in qiresult:
        logging.getLogger().info(row)
        userId = row["userId"]
        break

except Exception as e:
    logging.getLogger().error("Error occurred: %s", str(e))

# Check for results
if not qiresult:
    logging.getLogger().info("No results found or query execution failed")


When I run this code, I encounter the following error:
PREPARE: Illegal Argument: Error: at (3, 16) missing '(' at '$nickname', at line 3:16
rule stack: [parse, statement, index_function_path, func_call]

I've tried different variations, including combining the variable declarations into a single DECLARE statement, but I keep running into syntax errors. Here are some of the variations I tried:
Declaring multiple variables in a single line:
DECLARE $mailaddress STRING, $nickname STRING;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mailaddress = $mailaddress AND nickname = $nickname

Despite these attempts, I continue to face errors.
My questions are:
What is the correct way to declare and use variables in Borneo SQL queries?
Are there any specific syntax rules or best practices for using variables with Borneo?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I have solved the issue myself. Here's what I did:
statement = '''
DECLARE $mailaddress STRING;
$nickname STRING;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE mailaddress = $mailaddress AND nickname = $nickname
'''

Thank you for the suggestions and assistance.
